# What is the role of _ in this expression?

Tags: syntax

I'm fairly familiar with basic Mathematica, but some of its more advanced syntax (especially certain special characters) eludes me.

In the *Scope* section in the documentation of [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect.html), there's this curious bit at the end:

```
D[f[Sqrt[x^2 + 1]], {x, 3}];
Collect[%, Derivative[_][f][_], Together]
```

I understand that [`_`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html) indicates any valid expression — it's essentially Mathematica's wildcard character.

**In the above example, what do each of the blanks correspond to, syntactically?**

I'm guessing the first blank indicates "collect terms of any order derivative", so the first blank corresponds to *derivative order*. If so, what about the second blank?

Along the same lines, why is there the third argument (`[_]`) at all? Shouldn't `Derivative` only have two bracketed arguments, the first indicating the set of derivative orders and the second indicating the function?

Comment: That would be the argument of the function `Derivative[n][f]`. As a concrete example: `Derivative[2][Sin][x]` is the same as `-Sin[x]`.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to follow if you try out `Derivative[1][Cos[#] &]`. Since it returns another function (`-Sin[#1] &`), it too can be applied. `Derivative[n]` is a function which *takes a function* and *returns a function*, hence the 3 brackets.

By the way, try `FullForm` on the expression that is being collected on to see how you could precisely determine the pattern yourself: `D[f[Sqrt[x^2 + 1]], {x, 3}] // FullForm`

Finally, note that square brackets are actually a pattern structure. Example:

```
f[a_][b_] := a + b;

partials = f /@ Range[10]
Through[partials[100]]
```

This is generally refered to as Currying/partial application. I think in Mathematica it's rarely necessary and often confusing (mainly as a matter of convention), but it makes sense in the case of Derivative.

Comment: Another way of looking at the effect of `Derivative[]` is to use `Operate[]`: `Operate[Derivative[2], Sin[x]]` yields the second derivative `-Sin[x]`.